# can't get output parameters from a SqlParameter inside a query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlparameter

I'm doing a simple `INSERT` query into my database. The column `id` have auto-generated ID and i need it for another query. I read i can get the generated id using a parameter in output direction, so i wrote this code:

```
string id;
queryString = "INSERT INTO tr_text (form, item, enabled, programID) VALUES (@myForm, @myItem, 1, @myProgramID)";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.CommandText = queryString;
    command.Parameters.Add("@myForm", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = form;
    command.Parameters.Add("@myItem", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = item;
    command.Parameters.Add("@myProgramID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "id");
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    id = command.Parameters["@id"].Value.ToString();
 }
```

My query is executed correctly (i have the correct new record in my database) but my `id` variable is still empty! how can i make that code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query, because you do not set @id to any value

```
INSERT INTO tr_text (form, item, enabled, programID) VALUES (@myForm, @myItem, 1, @myProgramID) 
set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Answer (score 3):

Please change your query like that;

```
 INSERT INTO tr_text (form, item, enabled, programID) 
 OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
 VALUES (@myForm, @myItem, 1, @myProgramID)
```

and use ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteNonQuery() like that;

```
 Int32 id= (Int32) command.ExecuteScalar();
```